# Starting Off Point - Java Safecracker Program

Tags: java, algorithm

**I'm a Java newbie that's having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around a lab we were recently assigned.  I was hoping that someone out there might help me understand where to start with the problem and some tips to get through it - NOTE: I'M NOT ASKING FOR SOMEONE TO WRITE THE CODE FOR ME.  I just need a little explanation.  The problem is as follows:**

"The item is locked in a Klein safe behind a painting in the second-floor library. Klein safes are extremely rare; most of them, along with Klein and his factory, were destroyed in World War II. Fortunately old Brumbaugh, from research, knew Klein's secrets and wrote them down before he died.

A Klein safe has two distinguishing features: a combination lock that uses letters instead of numbers, and an engraved quotation on the door. A Klein quotation always contains between five and twelve distinct uppercase letters, usually at the beginning of sentences, and mentions one or more numbers. Five of the uppercase letters form the combination that opens the safe. By combining the digits from all the numbers in the appropriate way you get a numeric target. (The details of constructing the target number are classified.)

To find the combination you must select five letters `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` that satisfy the following equation, where each letter is replaced by its ordinal position in the alphabet (`A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26`). The combination is then `vwxyz`. If there is more than one solution then the combination is the one that is lexicographically greatest, i.e., the one that would appear last in a dictionary."

```
v - w2 + x3 - y4 + z5 = target
```

"For example, given target 1 and letter set `ABCDEFGHIJKL`, one possible solution is `FIECB`, since `6 - 92 + 53 - 34 + 25 = 1`. There are actually several solutions in this case, and the combination turns out to be `LKEBA`.

Klein thought it was safe to encode the combination within the engraving, because it could take months of effort to try all the possibilities even if you knew the secret. But of course computers didn't exist then."

=== Op tech directive ===
"Develop a Java program to find Klein combinations in preparation for field deployment. Use standard test methodology as per departmental regulations. Input consists of one or more lines containing a positive integer target less than twelve million, a space, then at least five and at most twelve distinct uppercase letters. The last line will contain a target of zero and the letters END; this signals the end of the input. For each line output the unique Klein combination, or 'no solution' if there is no correct combination. Use the exact format shown below."

Example input:

```
1 ABCDEFGHIJKL
11700519 ZAYEXIWOVU
3072997 SOUGHT
1234567 THEQUICKFROG
0 END
```

Example output:

```
LKEBA 
YOXUZ 
GHOST 
no solution
```

**The professor scribbled some code down, but I'm just having a hard time making sense of it - that is as follows:**

```
package lab2;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static final int MAX_LETTERS = 12;
        public static final int MIN_LETTERS = 5;
        private String best; //best solution;
        private int key;   // number in input file
        private int codes;   // number of letters in code
        int [] k = new int [MAX_LETTERS];  //holds numeric codes
        public boolean is_solution (int u, int v, int x, int x, int y){  //compute the equation, test if it equals to key, return true or false
        }//is_solution
        public void test_combinations(int start){
            int i;
            if (start == MIN_LETTERS){
                if (is_solution(k[0], k[1], k[2], k[3], k[4])){
                    char[] s = new char[5];
                    s[0] = (char) (k[0] + 'A' - 1);
                    s[1] = (char) (k[1] + 'A' - 1);
                    s[2] = (char) (k[2] + 'A' - 1);
                    s[3] = (char) (k[3] + 'A' - 1);
                    s[4] = (char) (k[4] + 'A' - 1);
                    String sol = Arrays.toString(s);
                    System.out.println("\n Found a Solution " + sol);
                    if (sol.compareTo(best) > 0)
                        best = sol;
                }//close if is_solution
            }//if start
            else{
                for (i = start; i<codes; i++){
                    temp = k[start];
                    k[start] = k[i];
                    k[i] = temp;
                    test_combinations(start+1);
                    k[i] = k[start];
                    k[start] = temp;
                }//close for
            }//close else
        }//test_combinations

        public lab2(){
            //file
            //try/catch
            //inside try: read key, read code in a loop - WHILE.HASNEXT
            //test if(key == 0), break
            //test code.lenth is between 5 & 12, if not, break
            //set best to "@@@@@@@"
            //convert all characters to ordinal values, store them in array k - SUBTRACT 'A' ADD 1 - CHAR.AT
            charAt(i)-'A'+1 ______ k[i] (assign to)
                test_combinations(0);
            //output best
            //close file
        }//lab2
    }
}
```

Comment: He has given you the code that generates the possible combination. You must provide the logic that checks if a combination is a possible key (in `is_solution`) and the code to initialize the program (by reading the key from a file) in `lab2()`

Comment: Please clean up the formatting on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a For loop to convert your chars into an ordinial value to store into array k. That should help so it'd be

> if (codeLength > 5 && codeLength < 12){
>
> > for(int i; i < codeLength; i++){
> >
> > > k[i] = charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;

I haven't figured out what to put in the while loop parenthesis, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Lab2() code is as follows:

```
    public Lab2() {
    File Safe = new File("Safe.txt");
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(Safe);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            key = input.nextInt();
            String s = input.next();
            if (key == 0){
                break;
            }            
            if (s.length() < 5 || s.length() > 12){
                break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                k[i] = s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
            }                  
            codes = s.length();
            //System.out.printf("Key %d, letters %s (%d) \n," key, s, codes);  
            best = ("@@@@@");//set best to "@@@@@@@"          
            test_combinations(0);
            if (best.equals("@@@@@")) {
                System.out.println("No solution.");
            }
                else {
                System.out.println("Best solution: " + best);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Execute this.");
    }
}
```